# R - Select pairwise cases based on reduction of missing data

Tags: r, select, na

I am trying to figure out how I could subset a database based on the best combinaison of missing.

My data look like this

```
   Country.Name X2010.x X2011.x X2012.x X2010.y X2011.y X2012.y
20      Belarus   15080   16410   16800   27.72   26.46      NA
21      Belgium   38810   40210   39870      NA      NA      NA
22       Belize    7720    7940    8170      NA      NA      NA
23        Benin    1590    1640    1710      NA      NA   43.53
24      Bermuda   69340   66640   66390      NA      NA      NA
25       Bhutan    6140    6680    6960      NA      NA   38.73
 ...............................................................
```

each `year .x` as to be selected with each `year .y`
If there is a missing in either `.x` or `.y`, I can't choose the pairwise combinaison.

In the end, what I need is a database without `NA`. It does not matter what year has been selected for each country, `.x` and `.y` just have to be to same year.

If I look at the distribution of missing between `.x` and `.y`, I can see that choosing `X2011` would be the best combinaison.

```
colSums(is.na(data)) 
Country.Name      X2010.x      X2011.x      X2012.x      X2010.y      X2011.y      X2012.y 
       0            3            3            3           21           19           22
```

But I guess that it is the best combinaison **overall** but not for each specific country.

**I just need to keep the maximum number of countries in the data**.

How could I maximise the selection of countries based on their specific missing cases ? 
Do you understand my issue ?

Any advices?

Not optimal but possible outcome :

```
   Country.Name     .x     .y
20      Belarus   15080   27.72
31     Bulgaria   13950   35.78
35     Cambodia    2350   33.55
37       Canada   39200   33.68
45        China    9010   42.06

 # 
 data = select(data, Country.Name, X2010.x, X2010.y)
 data = na.omit(data)
```

The dataset

```
data <- structure(list(Country.Name = c("Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", 
  "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
  "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", 
  "Burundi", "Cabo Verde", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Caribbean small states", 
  "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Central Europe and the Baltics", 
  "Chad", "Channel Islands", "Chile", "China"), X2010.x = c(15080, 
  38810, 7720, 1590, 69340, 6140, 4950, 8860, 12500, 13520, NA, 
  13950, 1390, 710, 5630, 2350, 2390, 39200, 13141.13583, NA, 880, 
  19213.13055, 1850, NA, 17010, 9010), X2011.x = c(16410, 40210, 
  7940, 1640, 66640, 6680, 5200, 9310, 13930, 14030, NA, 14790, 
  1430, 730, 5960, 2530, 2470, 40570, 12973.98051, NA, 910, 20391.27796, 
  1850, NA, 19040, 9940), X2012.x = c(16800, 39870, 8170, 1710, 
  66390, 6960, 5400, 9290, 14630, 14350, NA, 15250, 1550, 750, 
  6220, 2710, 2550, 41170, 13245.52928, NA, 950, 20765.62768, 1930, 
  NA, 20140, 10890), X2010.y = c(27.72, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, 35.78, NA, NA, NA, 33.55, NA, 33.68, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 42.06), X2011.y = c(26.46, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, 46.26, NA, NA, 53.09, NA, 34.28, NA, NA, NA, 31.82, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, 43.3, NA, 50.84, NA), X2012.y = c(NA, NA, NA, 
  43.53, NA, 38.73, 46.64, NA, NA, 52.67, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Country.Name", 
  "X2010.x", "X2011.x", "X2012.x", "X2010.y", "X2011.y", "X2012.y"
  ), row.names = 20:45, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide the desired output on the basis of sample data.

Comment: The expected output is not corresponding to the example data.  May be `library(data.table);melt(setDT(data), measure.vars=list(2:4, 5:7), na.rm=TRUE, 
    value.name=c('x', 'y'))[, lapply(.SD, max), Country.Name, .SDcols=x:y]`

Comment: In the description, you mentioned that selecting 2011 year would be best for the overall combination.  But, then in the expected you are selecting 2010 value for Belarus.  The value is less than 16410.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` and `tidyr` solution:

```
data %>%
  gather(YearXY, Value, -Country.Name, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  separate(YearXY, c("Year", "XY")) %>%
  spread(XY, Value) %>% filter(!is.na(x) & !is.na(y)) %>%
  group_by(Country.Name) %>%
  slice(1)
```

Note that it omits countries which have no year that has both x and y.

For random years, replace `slice(1)` with:

```
mutate(Random = sample(n())) %>%
  filter(Random == 1) %>%
  select(-Random)
```

Comment: A similar option with devel version of data.table is `melt(setDT(data), measure.vars=list(2:4, 5:7), value.name=c('x', 'y'))[!is.na(x) & !is.na(y)][, .SD[1L] , Country.Name][,variable:=NULL][]`

Comment: @Nick K - i get this error message ; `Error in matrix(unlist(pieces), ncol = n, byrow = TRUE) : 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'`

Comment: @giacomoV  Based on the dput output, I am not getting any error using `dplyr_0.4.1.9000`

Comment: @giacomoV nor am I. I'm using current release versions of `dplyr` and `tidyr`. Are you sure your data is called `data` and is a `data.frame`?

Comment: @NickK - my versions:  `dplyr_0.4.2` and `tidyr_0.2.0`. I just tried on the edited data you proposed and i get the error. It comes from the line `separate(YearXY, c("Year", "XY"))`

Comment: @giacomoV the error is actually happening within a function in `stringr`. What versions of `stringr` and `stringi` are you using?

Comment: the versions are : `stringi_0.5-5` and `stringr_1.0.0` - I will try to update and check. Thanks for your patience !

Comment: @giacomoV those are current; just checked and all works fine here with the same versions. Not sure if it's a locale issue or something else.

Comment: @NickK - now it is working. Thanks. Just a small thing - instead of (in the end)  `first` I would rather use then something like randomly pick a country. Thanks again

Comment: @giacomoV I assume you mean a random year, not country. See edit.